# What is alternative for middle-click paste in xorg?

Tags: xorg, shortcuts

Well yeah I have a problem, I'm using trackball and I don't have middleclick, I even don't want to have it. i can't figure out what is the shortcut to paste it that way? because if you want to copy something from xterm you need to use middleclick. Ctrl+V and Shift+INS is using another clipboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Push both left and right buttons at the same time. If you prefer keyboard shortcuts take a look to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11889/pasting-x-selection-not-clipboard-contents-with-keyboard).

Answer (score 5):

In *most* X11 programs, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd> should work – it pastes from the same "PRIMARY" selection that xterm copies to.

If you need to paste to Firefox or Chromium, though, you will need a program that synchronizes both selections, such as [Klipper](http://userbase.kde.org/Klipper) (KDE), [Parcellite](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/)/[Clipit](http://clipit.rspwn.com/) (GNOME), or [loliclip](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=144741) (generic). [The term is "clipboard manager".]

---

Alternatively, **configure Xterm to copy to the "CLIPBOARD" selection** instead, by adding one of the following to your `~/.Xresources` file:

2. Retain normal behavior when selecting, but copy to "CLIPBOARD" when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is pressed:

   ```
   XTerm*vt100*translations:   #override           \n\
       Shift <Key> Delete: insert-selection(SELECT)    \n\
       Shift Ctrl <Key> C: select-end(CLIPBOARD)       \n\
       Shift Ctrl <Key> V: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
       Shift Ctrl <Key> N: spawn-new-terminal()        \n
   ```
3. Always copy to "CLIPBOARD" when selecting:

   ```
   XTerm*selectToClipboard: true
   ```

(Run `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` after editing.)

Comment: and why not .Xdefaults? with dwm it's loading by default

Comment: sorry for not selecting your answer, but 'choutos' actually answered the question. Although I will use your hack anyway =)